# Select all elements with class name start by specific string by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML DOM:

```
<div id="d1" class="Addable"><span class="yak-bak-nak vok-do-maria"> <p>Goola1</p>
<span>volaa</span></span></div>

<div id="d2" class="Addable"><span class="yak-bak-val vok-do-maria"> <p>Goola2</p></span></div>

<div id="d3" class="Addable"><span class="vok-do-maria yak-bak-nak"> <p>Goola3</p></div>

<div id="d4" class="Addable"><span class="vok-do-maria yak-bak-nak"> <p>Goola4</p></div>

<input type="button" class="Doop" value="Do" />
```

So I want to remove all `divs` that class names start with "yak-bak" that means all of the above.

so I try this script:

```
$('.Doop').click(function () {

    $('span[class|="yak-bak"]').parent('div').remove();
});
```

but just d1 and d2 remove and d3, d4 remain because the `yak-bak` class come as second also I try this:

```
$('.Doop').click(function () {

    $('span[class^="yak-bak"]').parent('div').remove();
});
```

So what is your suggestion? where is the problem?

Comment: Whoa, whoa. Can't you just give the ones you want a class of `yak-bak` and select that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To target elements with multiple classes, where one of then starts by "yak-bak" at the beginning of the attribute class, or at the middle of it, you can use:

**JQUERY**

```
$("div[class^='yak-bak'],div[class*=' yak-bak']").parent('div').remove();
```

*This will select elements where the class starts by "yak-bak" and elements that contain a class stated by "yak-bak".*

Comment: Thanks for answer, I think this is better :`$('span[class*="yak-bak"]').parent('div').remove();`

Comment: @Saeid, what best serves your needs :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').filter(function() {
  return $(this).has('span[class^="yak-bak"]');
}).remove();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/18/)**

Or

```
$('div').filter(function() {
  return $(this).has('span[class^="yak-bak"], span[class*=" yak-bak"]');
}).remove();
```

But First one will enough.

Comment: That will target all elements where the class attribute starts with "yak-bak", not all that have a class started by "yak-bak". I believe that the OP intends to target elements with a certain class that starts with "yak-bak".